# Onchange event not fired in asp TextBox of type "date"

Tags: .net, vb.net, onchange

I have this textbox, type=DATE, in a page.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="IDOrderReqDate" type="date" AutoPostBack="true"
                        ToolTip="Seleziona the date" onchange="DataChanged" />
```

I need to do some things when the user selects a date.
I defined the "onchange" event, but it isn't fired.
If I remove "type=DATE", the event is fired, but this way I loose the calendar (useless solution).

Any solution?
Any other event?

Comment: I don't see a type property or an onchange event for a TextBox.

Comment: You don't see type="date" and onchange="DataChanged"
?

Comment: That is correct. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox?view=netframework-4.8 Am I looking at the wrong TextBox? If so please direct me docs.